# What is wrong with the short circuit logic in this Java code?

Tags: java, logical-operators

Why doesn't func3 get executed in the program below? After func1, func2 doesn't need to get evaluated but for func3, shouldn't it?

```
if (func1() || func2() && func3()) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}

public static boolean func1() {
    System.out.println("func1");
    return true;
}

public static boolean func2() {
    System.out.println("func2");
    return false;
}

public static boolean func3() {
    System.out.println("func3");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This raises the point that in any sort of non-trivial expression like that, it's a good idea to declare your intent with parentheses. So even if you intended
(func1() || (func2() && func3()), you make it explicit and clear to programmers who come along later that your code is working as intended.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're using a short-circuited or.  If the first argument is true, the entire expression is true.

It might help if I add the implicit parentheses that the compiler uses

**Edit**: As Chris Jester-Young noted, this is actually because logical operators have to left-to-right associativity:

```
if (func1() || (func2() && func3()))
```

After func1 returns, it becomes this:

```
if (true || (func2() && func3()))
```

After evaluating the short-circuited or, it becomes:

```
if (true)
```

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, this is because && has higher precedence than ||. Associativity is, in both cases, left-to-right.

Comment: I mention this because otherwise this post would lead to the question of, why (A || (B && C)) as opposed to ((A || B) && C).

Comment: (It's important to night that it is precedence which is important here, no associativity doesn't get a look in. IMO, expressions such as `a || b && c` and `a && b || c` (which is `(a && b) || c) are confusing and the compiler should complain.)

Answer (score 6):

Java functions are evaluated according to [precedence rules](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/precedence.html)

because "&&" is of higher precendence than "||", it is evaluated first because you did not have any brackets to set explicit precedence

so you expression of

```
(A || B && C)
```

which is

```
(T || F && F)
```

is bracketed as

```
(T || (F && F))
```

because of the precedence rules.

Since the compiler understands that if 'A == true' it doesn't need to bother evaluating the rest of the expression, it stops after evaluating A.

If you had bracketed `((A || B) && C)` Then it would evaluate to false.

**EDIT**

Another way, as mentioned by other posters is to use "|" and "&" instead of "||" and "&&" because that stops the expression from shortcutting.
However, because of the precedence rules, the end result will still be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Java short-circuits boolean expressions. That means that, once `func1()` is executed and returns `true`, the rest of that boolean doesn't matter since you are using an `or` operator. No matter what `func2() && func3()` evaluates to, the whole expression will evaluate to `true`. Thus, Java doesn't even bother evaluating the `func2()` or `func3()`.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 2):

Java uses Lazy evaluation.

Since Func1 always returns true,  the entire expression MUST be true, so it shortcuts the rest of the expression.

```
true || (???)
```

and

```
false && (???)
```

will always shortcut.

To turn off shortcut evaluation, use | and & instead of || and &&

We can use this to good effect:

```
String s;
if (s != null && !s.equals("")) ...
```

Meaning that if s is null, we won't even have to try to call s.equals, and we won't end up throwing an NullPointerException

Comment: It won't always shortcut. It's evaluating according to precedence rules. I don't have a java compiler handy, but I believe that (falsefunc() && true1() || true2()) will evaluate falsefunc() then true2().

Answer (score 2):

You're using the shortcut-operators || and &&. These operators don't execute the rest of the expression, if the result is already defined. For || that means if the first expression is true and for && if the first expression is false.

If you want to execute all parts of the expression use | and & instead, that is not shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

since func1() yelds true there is not need to continue evaluation since it is always true

Answer (score 1):

If function 1 always returns true, then Java doesn't need to evaluate the rest of the expression to determine that the whole expression will be true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all functions to be executed you can drop the short-cut variants

```
if (func1() | func2() & func3()) {
```